# running a multiple instance of a method Simultaneously c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

which on is better for that purpose and why?
tanks :)

I check the first one and test it ; its going to work perfectly but I want to know which one is a right way to do t

```
        List<int> aa = new List<int>();
        aa.Add(1);
        aa.Add(2);
        aa.Add(3);
        foreach (var iu in aa)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartFollowState(iu));
        }
```

or

```
        List<int> aa = new List<int>();
        aa.Add(1);
        aa.Add(2);
        aa.Add(3);
        Parallel.ForEach(lstiu, iu =>
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartFollowState(iu));
        });
```

Comment: ya but I want to know which one is better on that topic its not saying which one is better

Comment: did you look on the first answer there?

Comment: I agree with Yarimi. The answer he linked is basically the same question, and the answer given answers yours.  The accepted answer literally says "The first is a much better option" and explains why.